# Using Handlebars link-to for nested routes

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In an Ember-based project I have book object that consists an array of chapters, each of which is an array of sections.

I also have a nested route that looks like this:

```
  this.resource('book', { path: 'book/:id' }, function() {
        this.resource('section', { path: 'chapter/:chapter_num/section/:section_num'});
  });
```

In my handlebars template I have something that looks like this for the menu:

```
   <ul>
        <li>{{#link-to 'book' this}}Home{{/link-to}}</li>
        {{#each chapter in chapters}}
            <li>{{title}}</li>
            <ul>
                {{#each section in sections}}
                    <#link-to ???WHAT TO PUT HERE???>{{section}}</link-to>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        {{else}}
            <li>No chapters</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

I am struggling to come up with a proper way to generating a route to the given section where the output would be something to the effect of:

e.g:

*book/1234567/chapter/3/section/4   for Chapter 3, Section 4*

*book/1234567/chapter/1/section/2   for Chapter 1, Section 2*

One, I am not sure how to get access to the index of the current chapter and section I am about to create a link for, and two, I am not sure how to create a nested route for the given section.

I am still quite new to Ember so any tips here would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Ember.Route's serialize and model methods to handle the url, and just send the section to the link to.

use
`{{#link-to 'book.section' book section}}`

and do something like this in the route:

```
App.SectionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
      var book = this.modelFor('book');
      return book.getChapter(params.chapter_num).getSection(params.section_num);
  },

  serialize: function(section) {
      return { 
          chapter_num: section.get("chapter.id"),
          section_num: section.get("id")
      };
  }
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your route to this:

```
this.resource('book', { path: 'book/:id' }, function() {
        this.resource('chapter', { path: 'chapter/:chapter_num'}, function(){
             this.resource('section', { path: 'section/:section_num' });
        });
});
```

Then you can add the route by doing:

```
{{#link-to 'book.chapter.section' book chapter section}} {{section}} {{/link-to}}
```

At least, I think that should work. You may need to change `num` to `id`.

Comment: But what if the chapter route isn't really meaningful and really doesn't make sense without a section appending it?   And the other part to the question is how can I actually get access to the indices of said chapter and section compared to the actual model of it?